# Issue with `TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED` when calling Uniswap contract - but I am approving the token!

Tags: solidity, uniswap, kovan

My code is pretty simple

```
function swapForEth(address tokenAddress, 
    uint amountIn, 
    uint amountOutMin, 
    address to, 
    uint deadline) external onlyOwner payable {

    require(IERC20(tokenAddress).approve(UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS, uint256(-1)));

    address[] memory path = new address[](2);
    path[0] = tokenAddress;
    path[1] = uniswap.WETH();

    uniswap.swapExactTokensForETH(amountIn, amountOutMin, path, to, deadline);
}
```

As you can see. I am approving the token with `uint256(-1)` so not sure the error i am getting in my transaction is `TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED`

Please see transaction here https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x86d4667699a86bc0bd49d7ae54bfb51b406c25f08b499b0a607e2d974bb68c68

I'd verify the contract bytecode but unfortunately I've changed my contract a bit since then so having some trouble doing so lol... if needed can post a larger portion of the contract

Comment: Hi there. The error will be coming from the `.swapExactTokensForETH()` call, so you'll need to check the sanity of all the arguments you're passing in.

Comment: Thanks Richard! It definitely is coming from that call, but I think the error implies that my contract is not approved to transfer the tokens - but my require statement does that? Very confused.

Comment: Can you check the allowance for `tokenAddress`/`UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS` by calling `allowance()` on the ERC20 contract manually? If that checks out, then it's not the approval that's the issue.

Comment: Hmm it seems the allowance is still 0... https://gyazo.com/363306b760c5c47d164641d07b603150

My contract does not appear to have approved the UniswapV2 contract

Comment: And also no emitted events here. https://ethtx.info/kovan/0x87d3fe6b2ca798a8f2aa87ae659f76b0098cba4d19de607c3de64df0a104b119

Comment: I've removed the latter lines, it definitely calls approval - something else is off here. Will keep thinking, hmm https://ethtx.info/kovan/0x291f970e406495cda62af9841be6c61c7eb1565c02d8610bf93b2de59855fbd0

Comment: To your original comments, probably sanity of what I'm passing in

Comment: Yeah I was passing around msg.sender rather than address(this) https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0xfe80767fa4c8897d5f2eb5f833d8d7315e84bc37b382200b6d5974fb41ad07a3